# Unbound local error in maximum sub array problem from cormens algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, sum, max, dynamic-programming

I am trying to follow the Cormen's algorithm approach to solving maximum sum sub array problem using  Dynamic programming in Python.For this I have already created a maximum crossing sub array code which is working fine.

```
def maxcrosssub(arr, low, mid, high):
left_sum = float("-inf")
sum = 0
for i in range(mid, low-1, -1):
    sum += arr[i]
    if sum > left_sum:
        left_sum = sum
        max_left = i
right_sum = float("-inf")
sum = 0
for j in range(mid+1, high):
    sum += arr[j]
    if sum > right_sum:
        right_sum = sum
        max_right = j
return(max_left, max_right, left_sum+right_sum)
```

But the problem is in main program.

```
def max_subarray(arr, low, high):
if low == high:
    return (low, high, arr[low])
mid = (low+high)//2
left_low, left_high, left_sum = max_subarray(arr, low, mid)
right_low, right_high, right_sum = max_subarray(arr, mid+1, high)
cross_low, cross_high, cross_sum = maxcrosssub(arr, low, mid, high)

if left_sum >= right_sum and left_sum >= cross_sum:
    return(left_low, left_high, left_sum)
elif right_sum >= left_sum and right_sum >= cross_sum:
    return(right_low, right_high, right_sum)
else:
    return(cross_low, cross_high, cross_sum)
```

I am getting this error

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'max_right' referenced before assignment.
```

I have tried using global variable name following some answers in stack overflow but it is still not working.
Can anyone suggest what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The problem

The problem is coming from the first function `maxcrosssub`, precisely from the fact that in some cases `max_right` is used (referenced) before being initialized (assignment). For example if the condition `sum > left_sum` is never fulfilled.

## Solution

Assign a value to `max_right` in the beginning (before it's referenced)

## Try this

I am trying to follow the Cormen's algorithm approach to solving maximum sum sub array problem using Dynamic programming in Python.For this I have already created a maximum crossing sub array code which is working fine.

```
def maxcrosssub(arr, low, mid, high):
    left_sum = float("-inf")
    sum = 0
    
    # Here is where you can assign a value to 'max_right'
    max_right = 0    # For example
    
    for i in range(mid, low-1, -1):
        sum += arr[i]
        if sum > left_sum:
            left_sum = sum
            max_left = i
    right_sum = float("-inf")
    sum = 0
    for j in range(mid+1, high):
        sum += arr[j]
        if sum > right_sum:
            right_sum = sum
            max_right = j
    return(max_left, max_right, left_sum+right_sum)
```